# Mplayer/ SMPlayer general playing speed in Ubuntu

Tags: mplayer

How can I make it play **all** files slower/faster? I know that I can set the speed video by video with [ ] and { }. But I want to play faster a series of short videos, and I need something less tedious. Is there any setting for 'play all videos slower/faster by X%'?

Comment: Just curious... why?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the backend you have set up (either `mplayer` or more recently, `mpv`) you can pass the appropriate command line option.

For `mpv` the option is `--speed=$NUM` where `$NUM` is a number between `0.01` to  `100` (fast). 1 is the normal playback speed.

Go to the advanced settings panel of smplayer and simply add the speed flag as shown below. (settings shown for `mpv`)

[image: The settings]